# Generating table with loops through arrays in Angular

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I am generating a table with Angular and have a loop with another nested loop that is mostly working. The first loops through all the objects in the 'datasources' scope, and the second loops through the object's properties (which are arrays).

The only thing that I can't work out is how to display the object name/key.  I've tried {{ object }} but that doesn't display anything.

**Code:**

```
<tbody ng-repeat="object in datasources">
    <tr>
        <td>{{ object }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in object">
        <td>{{ key }}</td>
        <td>{{ value }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**Example of what is desired:**

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Title of Object 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Key 1</td>
        <td>Value 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Key 2</td>
        <td>Value 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Title of Object 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Key 1</td>
        <td>Value 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Key 2</td>
        <td>Value 2</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'key of the parent array'? do you mean what number of the loop you are on? if so use $index.

Comment: What you call an "array" seems to actually be an "object". Please post the JavaScript code initializing theses "arrays".

Comment: Sorry yes you are correct, they are actually objects. I'm using $http to query an API and then define $scope.dashboard. So I guess the API responds with a list of objects and their properties, so how do i get the object name/key from here? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### ng-repeat *hash* syntax

I'm guessing you're either needing to use

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in object">
```

where you iterate over the properties of the object **or** you need to target a hash property on your object via

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in object.hash">
```

### ng-repeat *array* syntax

For arrays you typically don't use the `(key, value) in target` syntax because the `key` is the same as the `$index`.  You can but it's completely unnecessary.  Instead for arrays you use

```
<tr ng-repeat="obj in object.arrayProperty">
```

---

**edit**

Based on comments below, it sounds like you just want to have some separation of the name of the object from its other properties.  You can do something like this:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="object in datasources">
    <tr>
        <td>{{ object.name }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in object" ng-if="key != 'name'">
        <td>{{ key }}</td>
        <td>{{ value }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Yeah I tried '(key, value) in object' and that gets me the objects properties, but my point that I want to get the name of the object before I loop through the properties?

Comment: Is the *name* of the object a property of the object itself like `object = {name: 'name', key: val, key: val}` or is the name elsewhere?

Comment: The name of the object is the key, it's not a property of the object.

Comment: In that case you need to use the first option I listed in my answer.  It's sounds like you want to pluck the name value from the object and isolate it from the other values.  I will update the answer to reflect that.